# How to tell if a variable is an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a Swift function that accepts Any and I want it to be able to accept an array of Strings, an array of Ints, a mixed array, or an array of arrays, etc. It also can accept just a String or an Int, etc, not in an array.

So I have this:

```
    private func parse(parameter: Any) {
        if parameter is Int {
            // Int
        } else if (parameter is Float) || (parameter is Double) {
            // Double
        } else if parameter is String {
            // String
        } else if parameter is Bool {
            // Bool
        } else if let array = parameter as? [Any] {
            // Should catch all Arrays
        } else {
            assert(false, "Unsupported type") // [String] ends up here
        }
    }
```

But if I call `parse(["Strings"])`, the assert is raised. How can I catch all types of Arrays?

edit - there was some confusion as to what I'm trying to accomplish. I basically need to return a String based on the type, so Int -> "" and String -> "", so an array would make recursive calls to return "..."

This post is marked as a duplicate, but that other question is about Javascript, not Swift.

Comment: user3352495  false, a check against [Any] still does not works as expected (Swift 5)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found the way to do that, which is to use `NSArray` for casting.

```
private func parse(x: Any) {
    if let o = x as? [Any] {
        println("[Any]")
    }
    if let o = x as? [AnyObject] {
        println("[AnyObject]")
    }
    if let o = x as? NSArray {
        println("NSArray")
    }
}

let a: [Any] = ["bar"]
let b: [AnyObject] = ["bar"]
let c = ["foo", 3.14]

parse(a) // ==> [Any]
parse(b) // ==> [AnyObject], and also NSArray
parse(c) // ==> NSArray
```

It look so that an array containing values of `Any` internally represented in `NSArray`.
(But should it be able to cast `c` to `[Any]`...? I'm suspecting it's a bug.)

Comment: Gimme a minute to try this idea in my implementation!

Comment: Bam! That works! I'm going to keep trying to simplify to get a good example to radar, but I'll use this in the mean time.

Comment: Swift 5 it looks like it doesn't work anymore..  "error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected element type 'AnyObject'" for line
let b: [AnyObject] = ["bar"]

Answer (score 7):

The key to understanding typing and type related issues in Swift is that all roads lead to protocols.

The challenge of this problem is detecting *any* type of array, not just one concrete type.  The OP's example failed because [Any] is not a base class or a generalized pattern of [String], that is to say, that (from what I can tell), in Swift [[T] is not covariant on T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).  Beyond that, you cannot check for SequenceType or CollectionType since they have associated types (Generator.Element).

The idiomatic solution is thus to use a *marker* protocol to indicate which types you want to match your criteria.  As illustrated below, you achieve this by creating an empty protocol, and associating it with the types of interest.

```
import Foundation


protocol NestedType {}
extension Array: NestedType {}
extension Set: NestedType {}
extension Dictionary: NestedType {}
extension NSSet: NestedType {}

protocol AnyTypeOfArray {}
extension Array: AnyTypeOfArray {}
extension NSArray: AnyTypeOfArray {}

protocol AnyTypeOfDictionary {}
extension Dictionary: AnyTypeOfDictionary {}


func printType(v:Any) {
    if v is NestedType {
        print("Detected a nested type")
    }

    if v is AnyTypeOfArray {
        print("\t which is an array")
    }

    else if v is AnyTypeOfDictionary {
        print("\t which is a dictionary")
    }
}


printType([String:Int]())
printType([Int]())
printType(NSArray())
```

The output of which is:

```
Detected a nested type
     which is a dictionary
Detected a nested type
     which is an array
Detected a nested type
     which is an array
```

Comment: This is the correct Answer. And the most "swifty" 

Answer (score 3):

One way you can do this is to separate the function out to two separate implementations (with the same name), one that takes an`Array` and one for everything else. You'll also need to make them generic functions instead of using the `Any` type. With that setup, Swift can use type inference to figure out the best function to call.

I'd implement it something like this (I'm just `println`ing the type to show where things end up):

```
func parse<T>(parameter: T) {
    if parameter is Int {
        println("Int")
    } else if (parameter is Float) || (parameter is Double) {
        println("Double")
    } else if parameter is String {
        println("String")
    } else if parameter is Bool {
        println("Bool")
    } else {
        assert(false, "Unsupported type")
    }
}

func parse<T>(parameter: Array<T>) {
    println("Array")
    for element in parameter {
        // Recursively parsing...
        parse(element)
    }
}
```

Then calling it like this:

```
parse(1)  // Int
parse(0.1) // Double
parse("asdf") // String
parse(true) // Bool
parse(["asdf", "asdf"]) // Array -> String String
```

Outputs:

```
Int
Double
String
Bool
Array
String
String
```

Comment: Running your code as is works perfectly. Running it in the context of my code, however, breaks it. I'm unpacking the parameters from an array of type [Any] and calling parse() on each element. No matter what the element is, the first function is called, never the second.

Comment: This fails: parseAny([["a", "b", "c"]])

func parseAny(values: [Any]) {
    for value in values {
        parse(value)
    }
}

Comment: And so does the same, except changing parseAny([Any]) to parseAny<T>(Array<T>)

Comment: Hmm, yep, you're right... offhand I'm not sure why, but I'll think about it a bit and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is some sort of wrapper struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_stdlib_getTypeName` that returns the mangled type name for the given value.

For example:

```
    var myString = "String"
    var myInteger = 10
    var myArray = [10,22]
    var myDictionary = ["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]
    println("\(_stdlib_getTypeName(myString))")
    println("\(_stdlib_getTypeName(myInteger))")
    println("\(_stdlib_getTypeName(myArray))")
    println("\(_stdlib_getTypeName(myDictionary))")
```

The result will be:

```
_TtSS // for String
_TtSi // for integer
_TtSa // for array
_TtVSs10Dictionary // for dictionary
```

Comment: This would technically let me know when I've been given array, but wouldn't let me treat it as an array without trying to cast it. The problem is, a forced downcast using `parameter as [Any]` causes a runtime crash. Also, this is super hacky.